# How to get row_number in Sqlce compact edition

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm using sqlserverce compact edition 3.
I need to get the rownumber from the table.
I have a table called system with column IPaddrs.
I need to get the IPaddrs and I need to append some text as its prefix like 'system_1(IPaddrs)'
I need to chage the number(1) every time row by row and need to show like.  'system_1(IPaddrs)',
 'system_2(IPaddrs)', 
'system_3(IPaddrs)'
How Can I get the rownumber.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an 'Id' column (or something with similiar name) that has a automatic Identity on it and you can then return the inserted row id from @@IDENTITY

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167(v=sql.80).aspx